# How do I do deterministic RSA in Go

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa

I have two go services, let's call them A and B. B holds an RSA key pair, while A only knows the public key. I want them to know if they agree on some value V.

I want to do this by having `B` encrypt encrypt `V` using the public key and have A do a comparison, but all the `crytpo/rsa` functions take an RNG which adds entropy and makes each hash of V different. That means I can't compare the hashes.

Is there a function in the go standard library that will deterministicly hash V?

Note: I can achieve this by using a fresh RNG seeded with the same value everytime I hash V, but I want to be able to compute this hash from other languages and that would tie me to Go's RNG.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with duskwuff that you're probably using the wrong primitive here. You might want to ask your non-programming related but conceptual question over on [security.se] first, before trying to implement it. This question likely suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/266187).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to do this by having `B` encrypt encrypt `V` using the public key and have A do a comparison…

You're using the wrong primitive.

If you want the owner of a private key to prove that they have some data, have them Sign that data. The recipient can Verify that signature using the public key.

Use the SignPSS and VerifyPSS methods to do this. The signature will not be deterministic, but it doesn't need to be -- the recipient will still be able to verify it.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not quite what I need to prove. I want A to only have hashes of V and to know if it has a different value than B. If it does, I want B to receive the new hash for decryption.

Comment: You may need to explain your security requirements in a bit more detail -- from what you've described, it's not clear why encryption is needed at all. (Why couldn't Bob just take a hash of V and send the hash to Alice in the clear?)

Comment: Agree with @duskwuff. If the hash is all that matters, just send the raw SHA256 value.

Comment: A third system gives Bob a hash of V, so that Bob can never know the plaintext of V.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for [EncryptOAEP](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP):

> The random parameter is used as a source of entropy to ensure that encrypting the same message twice doesn't result in the same ciphertext.

So the random data does not affect the reader's ability to decrypt the message with only the public key. The cipher text bytes will be different each time you encrypt the same value, which is a good thing.

Take a look at the examples on Encrypt/Decrypt OAEP in those docs. It should be sufficient to get you moving the right direction.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. EncryptOAEP requires a parameter for entropy. The only thing I can do with EncryptOAEP is use the same seed every time I encrypt, which will tie my implementation to go.

Comment: I'm tending to agree with @duskwuff then that you are not using these schemes for their intended purposes. Without the randomized padding, there are trivial attacks to deduce the plaintext.

Comment: Could you link one? There are certainly vulnerabilities to using no padding but I would not go as far as calling any of those exploit trivial.

Comment: From a more [technical answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/32076/147463) OAEP tries to improve over the previous padding for resistance against chosen ciphertext attacks (not chosen plaintext attack: since the public key is public, anybody can encrypt anything at will)

Comment: Chosen ciphertext attacks require the plaintext to be known by an attacker